# How to read SMS from inbox without content provider?

Tags: android, sms

I am writing an android app to read SMS from inbox. I came to know after few days search, with content provider (**content://sms/inbox**) we can read SMS, but it is not part of android SDK, some mobiles won't support this.

I saw some tutorials in web, there i found how to catch incoming SMS by using a BroadcastReceiver. With this we can't read old sms in inbox.

My question is, Is it possible to read a SMS from Inbox without using Content Provider or BroadcastReceiver ?

If anybody know solution please reply me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Querying on content://sms/ and type=1 (received) works for me on multiple devices.I havent faced the issue on any device yet

Comment: I too didn't faced this problem with mobiles i used till now, but see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022177/1070591)

Comment: ok.. thanks. For now i don't think there is any other way to do the same.