# Search the Inbox content by given string

Tags: android, search, full-text-search, sms

I want to develop an application, the small part of which will search the string of message from an EditText in the Inbox of my device....

I have referred some links like

[Search sms Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301046/search-sms-inbox)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941228/how-to-read-all-sms-from-inbox-in-android-2-2-and-above

http://androidforums.com/android-applications/1773-how-read-sms-android.html

[Read all SMS from a particular sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870230/read-all-sms-from-a-particular-sender/10870333#10870333)

but could not make it possible...
can anyone plz help me with a useful piece of code...Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Refer to my comment for answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer but dont know if its the most efficient solution. Kindly correct me if there is some more efficient solution.

I first checked a particular text from Inbox to the text I inserted in Search Box. And if the text matches then I inserted it into the ArrayList. Finally I print whole ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList<String> check(String str)
{

    boolean fullContainsSub = str.toUpperCase().indexOf(content.toUpperCase()) != -1;
    //String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
    //item.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), ListView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    if(fullContainsSub)
    {
     itemList.add(str);
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

Here ***str*** is text from Inbox while ***content*** will be search box text.