# How to search word in SMS inbox within the application?

Tags: android, sms

I am new to Android. I want to know how to search by word in SMS inbox within the application. Can anyone help me. Please give me the source code if you could.

Answer (score 1):

** Use Content Resolver ("content://sms/inbox") to read SMS which are in inbox.**

```
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null,     null, null, null);    
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do{
   String msgData = "";
   for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
   {
       msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
   }
   if(msgData.contains(yourWord))
       ;// do something

   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been answered several times already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392584/search-the-inbox-content-by-given-string) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301046/search-sms-inbox) for pointer for instance.
Please do search for existing questions before creating new ones.

Comment: how to speed up search?
this will take time when lots of sms in inbox

Answer (score 0):

first you have to query the inbox content provider for sms

```
  Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
  Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id",      "address", "person", "date", "body" }, null, null,null);
```

Then search iterate and get sms body

```
      if(cur.getCount()>0) {
        while(cur.moveToNext()) {
            String smsBody = cur.getString(5);
            Log.v("body",smsBody);

            if(smsBody.contains("matching string")) {


            }
```

also refer this link

[how can i read inbox in android mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547352/how-can-i-read-inbox-in-android-mobile)